# Django QuerySet join across four tables, including ManyToMany?

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

Given the following models, my goal is to create a QuerySet that pulls all available Tag objects for a given PostCategory id. I know how to write this in SQL but can't figure out how to do it using the Django ORM. I believe I'm following best practices by defining the relationships on the Post object, and not the Tag, but QuerySet syntax pattern seems like it would expect me to start with Tag.objects.filter() but I don't see how.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PostCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)    

class Post(models.Model):
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    is_featured = models.BooleanField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(PostCategory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tags = Tag.objects.filter(post__category_id=postcategory_id).distinct()
```

Comment: you beat me to it, i figured it out before i got notified of an answer :) thanks!